# Why does Flow Builder Refresh Randomly?

Tags: lightning-flow-builder, flow-builder

I've had this happen many times where I'm working on a flow, and the screen refreshes randomly.

At first I thought I may have accidentally hit Ctrl + R or some other shortcut, but after repeated occurences, I have determined that is no the case.

Sometimes when the page refreshes it is not a big deal because I just saved it and there is no issue, but sometimes it attempts to refresh when I am in the middle of some unsaved changes. Every time this happens the screen prompts me to confirm the refresh and maybe lose progress, and I deny the refresh, but if I try to save after that, the flow will not actually save and then I'll lose progress. I verified that I am still logged in to the org, and is not an inability so save due to session timeout. And yes I know I should save often, and I do, but still happens.

**Anyone else have this happen sometimes? And know what causes this?**

Comment: Do you use OAuth access or have SSO enabled on the org? Take a look at your org's session settings to see if this is caused by session expiry (could relate to token refresh, perhaps?). Before you deny the refresh, if you duplicate the tab in your browser and allow this duplicate to refresh, does this solve the saving issue in the original tab (after you deny the refresh in that tab)?

Comment: Hi Phil, we do use SSO, but I have checked when this happens and the session is still active when this happens. 

When I duplicate the window, the duplicated tab just shows the last saved version of the flow (which obviously does NOT show my latest edits) without a request to refresh since it essentially just loaded the page from the previous save data. The original tab keeps trying to refresh unfortunately.

I appreciate your thoughts on this!

Comment: I'd raise a Salesforce Support case...

Comment: Is there a deployment happening in the org for those instances where a refresh is forced?

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks for chiming in. No there is not a deployment going on when it happens. I have not been able to find a pattern yet. I also have not met anyone else that has had this issue so far